# The SonarCloud scan is analyzing the default master branch instead of the develop branch

Tags: azure-devops, sonarqube, azure-pipelines, devops, sonarcloud

How can I change the main branch to develop so that it directly publishes results on the SonarCloud dashboard, displaying the number of lines of code scanned, without the need to check the branch separately for viewing the results?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change which branch is treated as the main branch on sonarcloud as per the sonarsourcer replied [here](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/changing-default-main-branch-in-sonarcloud/94805/2).

But to display the result on overview page, checked on my side with DevOps pipeline, if you change the `dev1` branch as default branch(commit `c44b781b`):

[image]

After pipeline(SonarCloudAnalyze@1 and SonarCloudPublish@1 tasks), on the sonarcloud overview page, it will show the result correctly. Although on sonar cloud -> branches page, it will show master as main branch.

[image]

Comment: Hi, I have two branches. In the overview, it indicates that the 'master' branch hasn't been analyzed, but I want to set 'develop' as the default branch. Could you please provide a snapshot of how I can make this modification?

Comment: @DarshanC, you cannot change the main branch to others on SonarCloud side as i explained above, but you can change the default branch to `develop`(my first screenshot above which show dev1 on my side), when you build pipeline on `develop` branch and complete, it shows the result on overview sonarcloud overpage.

Comment: @DarshanC, may i know if there's any update? let me know if you still have any queries.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the below about changing your default branch in your repositry, if using Github, on the .github/workflows/build.yml in your repo, update the section:

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main    # The default branch
```

to have your specific branch.